# Get stream info of a user from Discord python API

Tags: youtube, discord.py, streaming, twitch

I want to post a notification when a member of the guild (discord server if you prefer) start streaming (twitch, youtube...) but I have trouble to use https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#streaming. Can you tell me for exemple how to retrieve the stream URL of a user using this class ?

When I print `user.activities`, I only get the stream name because I'm using the class Activities. But how to use the class Streaming from the link I provided you to retrieve informations about the stream of users ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Member.activities` is a tuple of `discord.BaseActivities`, you can loop through them and check if it's a `discord.Streaming` instance and use the `url` attribute

```py
member = # Any `discord.Member` instance
acts = member.activities

for act in acts: # Looping though every activity
    if isinstance(act, discord.Streaming): # Making sure it's the correct activity
        url = act.url
```

You can also use the `Member.activity` attribute if the user has only one activity

```py
act = member.activity

if isinstance(act, discord.Streaming):
    url = act.url
```

#### Reference:

- [`Member.activities`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.activities)
- [`Member.activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.activity)
- [`discord.BaseActivity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.BaseActivity)
- [`discord.Streaming.url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Streaming.url)